# how to change cells to a number if it is greater than a number in Excel

Tags: excel, cells

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a column of numbers in it. I want to tell it that if a cell in that column is greater than -9999 then I want it to set the value of that cell to -9999. How do I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use MIN:

```
=MIN(A1,-9999)
```

[image]

Comment: Ok this seems easy enough, so what if you wanted anything less than -9999 to equal -9999 then would you use the MAX function? Or how would you do this?

Comment: Yes just use the MAX instead of MIN. @Meghan

Comment: `=MAX(A1,-9999)` should not change the anything greater than -9999